# What's the difference between TEXT, CHAR, and VARCHAR in CockroachDB?

Tags: sql, varchar, cockroachdb

I see different schemas using `TEXT`, `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `CHARACTER VARYING`, `CHAR VARYING` to store string data. Which should I use in CockroachDB?

Answer (score 4):

All the types mentioned are equivalent; see the [CockroachDB STRING documentation](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/string.html#aliases) for an exhaustive list.

> In CockroachDB, the following are aliases for `STRING`:
>
> - `CHARACTER`
> - `CHAR`
> - `VARCHAR`
> - `TEXT`
>
> And the following are aliases for `STRING(n)`:
>
> - `CHARACTER(n)`
> - `CHARACTER VARYING(n)`
> - `CHAR(n)`
> - `CHAR VARYING(n)`
> - `VARCHAR(n)`

CockroachDB will treat all of these types identically. The canonical name for the type in CockroachDB, however, is `STRING`, so if you're starting a new application from scratch, you'll reduce confusion by preferring `STRING` over the other aliases.